# Making Symbolic links in Windows OS for CMake

Tags: cmake, symlink

I created soft symbolic links to files for my toolchain path. In CMake file I have command CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER, which must take path to my c compiler arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe. But path to this compilers are always changing when new update arrive. So instead of path "C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU Tools ARM Embedded/6 2017-q2-update/bin" I created symbolic link "C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU Tools ARM Embedded/gcc-compiler/bin", which point to previously file.But problem is now with symbolic link, it won't find "arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe" compiler.

So this code will work with no symbolic links and direct path to compiler.

But with symbolic link, it won't work, in build console it says:"arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe Not such a file or directory"

```
set(ARM_TOOLCHAIN_DIR "C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU Tools ARM Embedded/gcc-compiler/bin")
set(ARM_TOOLCHAIN_SUFFIX ".exe")
MAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER("${ARM_TOOLCAHIN_DIR}/arm-none-eabi-gcc${ARM_TOOLCAHIN_SUFFIX}" GNU)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When making symbolic links in Windows, which point to file where you have your compiler arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe. In your case you did symbolic link direct to point to file "/bin" in full path "C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU Tools ARM Embedded/6 2017-q2-update/bin". 
When command CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER takes your path with symbolic link as a parameter, Windows will not find a full path.

Solution is to make symbolic link to point only to the previous file, not to the finale file! So do **NOT** make symbolic link point to final file where your *.exe file is. Windows will not recognize your path.

So don't make it point to "/bin" but to here "C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU Tools ARM Embedded/6 2017-q2-update/".

In your case, use Windows Cmd command line and type:

```
mklink /D "C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU Tools ARM Embedded/gcc-arm-none-eabi/"  "C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU Tools ARM Embedded/6 2017-q2-update"
```

And now in your CMake file you can use this path to you C compiler:

```
set(ARM_TOOLCHAIN_DIR "C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU Tools ARM Embedded/gcc-compiler/bin")
MAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER("${ARM_TOOLCAHIN_DIR}/arm-none-eabi gcc.exe GNU)
```